# Nested resource with multiple parent resources in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a model to store comments related to articles. I have a strong feeling that in the future I will want comments on other objects in the app too. How do I design commenting in my app so that it will be forward compatible with adding new parent objects. I want to avoid a scenario where have multiple controllers/models for each object to comment relationship.

After watching Ryan Bates screen cast on [Nested Resource](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) I have a firm grasp on how tp nest a resource under a single parent. How do I achieve this under 2 or more parent resources?

Thanks!

Comment: +100 if you really have a "firm grasp" on nested resources :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For "forward compatible with adding new parent objects" part of the question:

You could use [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Here's a [nice example](http://kconrails.com/2010/10/19/common-addresses-using-polymorphism-and-nested-attributes-in-rails/). Also see [RailsCast #154](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association).

An example of how it could look like for you:

The `comments` table columns' could be like this:

```
id:integer
commentable_type:string
commentable_id:integer
comment_text:string
```

Some Sample records:

```
1,'Article',12,'My first comment' #comment on an Article model
2,'Question',12,'My first comment' #comment on a Question model
3,'Question',15,'My first comment' #comment on a Question model
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the part about the routes and finding the resource.

The usual rails controller would find the child resource from the parent.

```
GET /articles/{parent_id}/comments/{id}

GET /articles/0/comments/1

article = articles.find(parent_id = 0)
comment = article.comments.find(id = 1)
```

You can't do that with polymorphic parents. You would have to find the parent from the child.

```
GET /article/{parent_id}/comments/{id}
GET /questions/{parent_id}/comments/{id}

GET /article/0/comments/1
GET /questions/0/comments/1

parent = comments.select(parent_id = 0).parent
comment = parent.comments.find(id = 1)
```

It might possible to make your routes pass a type to the controller.

```
GET /{parent_type}/{parent_id}/comments/{id}

GET /article/0/comments/1
GET /questions/0/comments/1

parent = parent_type.find(parent_id = 0)
comment = parent.comments.find(id = 1)
```

(I've not tried this approach, this is obviously pseudocode.)

Edit ...

I suppose you could also just add one parameters for each type of parent.

```
GET /article/{article_id}/comments/{id}
GET /questions/{question_id}/comments/{id}

GET /article/0/comments/1
GET /questions/0/comments/1

if article_id
    article = articles.find(article_id = 0)
    comment = article.comments.find(id = 1)

if question_id
    question = questions.find(question_id = 0)
    comment = question.comments.find(id = 1)
```